# Submit master form

Tags: php, html

I will have multiple forms inside a form.

```
  <form id="masterform" method="POST" action="">

      <form id="form1" method="POST" action="">
            <input type="text" name="dataForm1">
            <input type="submit" id="form1Sub"/>
      </form>

      <form id="form2" method="POST" action="">
            <input type="text" name="dataForm2">
            <input type="submit" id="form2Sub"/>
      </form>

      <form id="form3" method="POST" action="">
            <input type="text" name="dataForm3">
            <input type="submit" id="form3Sub"/>
      </form>

            <input type="submit" id="formMasterSub"/>
  </form>
```

The structure of the form MUST be like that.

When I click the submit button of `form1sub` it only post the data inside the form `form1`, and so does when I click the submit `form2sub` it will only post the data of `form2`, and so on.

The most important thing now is:

When I click the submit button of `formMasterSub`, it submit all the data inside the whole form, such as `dataForm1`, `dataForm2`, and `dataForm3`.

Is it possible to do this? And if it is possible, how to correctly do this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't nest form elements like that, that markup is invalid.

Comment: You can't use nested form, You can use JS  to achieve this.

Comment: [It's invalid to have `<form>` inside `<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form). Browsers generally have high tolerance for errors like this so they render anyway, but that's still wrong. You can use "inspect element" to see the _actual_ structure your browser interpreted, it would most likely be not like you expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use nested form. Replace the submit button to simple button. And the individual and whole form submissions can be done using jquery like below:

**HTML**:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <form id="form1" method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="dataForm1">
        <input type="button" id="form1Sub"/>
  </form>
  <form id="form2" method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="dataForm2">
        <input type="button" id="form2Sub"/>
  </form>
  <form id="form3" method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="dataForm3">
        <input type="button" id="form3Sub"/>
  </form>
  <input type="button" id="formMasterSub"/>
```

**JQuery**:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form1Sub').click(function(){
        $('#form1').submit();
    });
    $('#form2Sub').click(function(){
        $('#form2').submit();
    });
    $('#form3Sub').click(function(){
        $('#form3').submit();
    });
    $('#formMasterSub').click(function(){
    var form1Data = $('#form1Sub').serialize();
    var form2Data = $('#form2Sub').serialize();
    var form3Data = $('#form3Sub').serialize();
       $.ajax({
            url: 'your url',
            data: {form1: form1Data, form2: form2Data, form3: form3Data}
       });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add name attribute to each nested form (respectively to its id, ex. `<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="">` ... and so on)

```
<input type="submit" id="formMasterSub" onclick="submitAllForms()" />
```

js part:

```
function submitAllForms(){
    document.forms['form1'].submit();
    document.forms['form2'].submit();
    document.forms['form3'].submit();
}
```

P.S. The other quys are right - your markup is initialy wrong